# Anaconda/osx - mudar a versão padrão de python

Tags: python, osx, anaconda

Eu estava usando python com anaconda no osx 10.8 e o spyder travou. Quando tentei reiniciar, o lançador mostrava o spyder como não estando instalado. Eu imaginei que o anaconda poderia ter tido algum problema e reiniciei o computador, mas o problema continuou.

Tentando descobrir a origem, notei que a versão padrão do python tinha mudado:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.4.1 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Tentei mudar de volta usando `defaults write`, refazendo o link com `ln -sf` e criando um `alias python=python2.7`, nada adiantou.

Então tentei usar o conda para remover o python3, mas `conda remove python3` não funciona. Usando o conda pra buscar pacotes instalados retorna isto:

```
$ conda search python
Fetching package metadata: ..
(...)
python                       1.0.1                         0  defaults        
                             (...)
                          .  2.7.5                         2  defaults        
                          .  2.7.5                         3  defaults        
                             (...)
                          *  3.4.1                         0  defaults
```

Tentei checar na documentação da Continuum, mas eles recomendam deixar o 2.7 como padrão e criar ambientes Anaconda para usar versões diferentes, o que também não me ajuda.

Alguém tem alguma idéia de como mudar o padrão de volta pra versão 2.7?

(Especificações do sistema: anaconda 1.7.0, osx 10.8.5, conda 3.5.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certo, encontrei um problema similar na mailing list da Continuum.

Resolvi o problema reinstalando o python usando o conda:

```
$ conda install python=2.7
Fetching package metadata: ..
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment /Users/kadu/anaconda:

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-3.5.2                |           py27_0         135 KB
    pycosat-0.6.1              |           py27_0          57 KB
    python-2.7.6               |                2        16.5 MB
    pyyaml-3.11                |           py27_0         149 KB
    requests-2.3.0             |           py27_0         564 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        17.4 MB

The following packages will be UN-linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-3.5.2                |           py34_0
    pycosat-0.6.1              |           py34_0
    python-3.4.1               |                0
    pyyaml-3.11                |           py34_0
    requests-2.3.0             |           py34_0

The following packages will be linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-3.5.2                |           py27_0   hard-link
    pycosat-0.6.1              |           py27_0   hard-link
    python-2.7.6               |                2   hard-link
    pyyaml-3.11                |           py27_0   hard-link
    requests-2.3.0             |           py27_0   hard-link

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Esse método também pode ser usado para escolher o pacote padrão no anaconda:

```
$ conda install python=3.4
Fetching package metadata: ..
Solving package specifications: .
Package plan for installation in environment /Users/kadu/anaconda:

The following packages will be UN-linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-3.5.2                |           py27_0
    pycosat-0.6.1              |           py27_0
    python-2.7.6               |                2
    pyyaml-3.11                |           py27_0
    requests-2.3.0             |           py27_0

The following packages will be linked:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-3.5.2                |           py34_0   hard-link
    pycosat-0.6.1              |           py34_0   hard-link
    python-3.4.1               |                0   hard-link
    pyyaml-3.11                |           py34_0   hard-link
    requests-2.3.0             |           py34_0   hard-link

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Vale avisar que fazer isso obriga o usuário a manualmente reinstalar qualquer outro pacote que seja usado. Eu precisei reinstalar o spyder, que parece ter causado o bug em primeiro lugar e presumivelmente foi reinstalado quando eu tentei lançá-lo na versão errada. Todas as outras bibliotecas, que eu não tentei reinstalar, voltaram a funcionar normalmente com a versão 2.7.